# How to insert into a mysql table only if not already existing?

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

A very simple question but I don't have the answer. I would like to insert a record into a table, but only if it doesn't already exist.

These are my tables:

- table1

  - id
- table2

  - idTable1 (FK: table1.id)
  - unik

I would like to insert into table2 only if the value to insert (unik) doesn't exist.

My first intuitions was to lock for update:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE unik = :unik FOR UPDATE;
IF (NOT EXISTS) 
  INSERT INTO table1 SET ...;
  INSERT INTO table2 SET idTable1 = LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...;
COMMIT;
```

But if the value doesn't exist, it won't lock anything and if two scripts run together, they will insert the same record.

My second intuition was to insert on duplicate key:

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET ...;
INSERT INTO table2 SET idTable1 = LAST_INSERT_ID(), ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idTable1 = idTable1;
```

But I already have to insert into table1 before table2 so what if I insert into table1 if finally nothing will be inserted into table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not doing something like:

```
START TRANSACTION

... DO SOME STUFF HERE
SAVEPOINT 'before_rollback';
INSERT INTO table1 SET ...;
INSERT INTO table2 SET idTable1 = LAST_INSERT_ID(), ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idTable1 = idTable1;

# A record exists, rollback to remove record in table1
if (affected_rows == 1)
{
   rollback 'before_rollback';
}
else
{
   commit;
}
```

Be careful: maybe MySQL will not "release" the consumed autincrement (depending of your MySQL conf: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

u can use count to see if there are or not like this

```
select count(*) thecount from table2 where unik = unikvalue
```

unikvalue is the value U want to search if exist or not

thecount here will have the number of row that founded

the general syntax is

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: yes but what if between the count request and the insert request, another script add a new "unik" value?

Comment: it's just the first line U will continue the code as U want

Comment: no it doesn't handle concurrency issue, imagine two scripts running together : the script 1 counts the number of rows with value "A" and found 0, at the same moment, the script 2 processes the same count with the same value "A" and found also 0 rows, so scripts 1 and 2 will want to insert the value "A"

Comment: the script take about 1 ms but to see the respond take more so it's impossible for this to happen
it's like if 2 insert new row at the same time with auto increment why every one take another id

Comment: There is a race condition. I already had the same problem, and I didn't know how to found a good solution

Comment: Robert : I have the problem. I work with many records databases (several millions) and I have a few scripts that runs at the same time. Sometimes, they want to process the same record... :(

Comment: so U need to make this column unique so now it's impossible to have two row with the same value

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (or something like this)

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id) (   
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL) TMP 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE uniq = :uniq)
)
```

Comment: it doesn't solve anything, if two processes run in the same time, they will both create a record into table1 (because unik doesn't exist on table2)